# How to convert MS Excel numbers in general format (e.g 43422) to date in python?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl, xlrd

After fetching data from Excel to Python, the dates have been fetched into python as '43422' format. How do I convert this integer to date format in python now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to prevent this from happening in the first place when you read in the data: `pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')`. Make sure that the data is properly formatted as a date before you read in the file.

If you want to convert this number to a date after you read it in, use the fact that it represents the number of days since January 1, 1900:

```
import datetime

d = '45422'

date = datetime.date(1900, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(int(d))
date
```

Output:

```
datetime.date(2024, 5, 12)
```

Comment: This ignores the fact that Excel considers 29th February to be a valid date, which it isn't. openpyxl contains utilities for handling time and date conversion.